# Merge / Loop thru data

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

Hello need to get insides from data, the desired_result is from VBA code that compare two sheets desired_result is checked and 100% accurate, If someone can assist me get the desired output, conditions are:

```
err['p'] == scr['p'] & err['errd'] >= scr['scrd'] & err['errq'] - scr['scrq'] >= 0
```

Its all about checking how many of `scr['n']` wenth thru err but if one passes thru err then `err['errq'] -= scr['scrq']` and jump to next item `scr['p']`, `scr['n']` are unique, please see the sample code below:

```
import pandas as pd

err = pd.DataFrame({
    'p' : ['10100.A','10101.A','10101.A','10101.A','10102.A','10102.A','10102.A','10103.A','10103.A','10147.A','10147.A'],
    'errd' : ['18-5-2022','16-5-2022','4-5-2022','13-5-2022','9-5-2022','2-5-2022','29-5-2022','6-5-2022','11-5-2022','25-5-2022','6-5-2022'],
    'errq' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 46, 1, 4, 1, 5]})
err = err.sort_values('errd')
scr = pd.DataFrame({
    'p' : ['10101.A','10101.A','10101.A','10102.A','10102.A','10102.A','10103.A','10147.A','10147.A','10147.A','10147.A','10147.A'],
    'scrd' : ['10-5-2022','10-5-2022','9-5-2022','13-5-2022','9-5-2022','9-5-2022','25-5-2022','6-5-2022','6-5-2022','6-5-2022','6-5-2022','11-5-2022'],
    'scrq' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'n' : ['7000000051481339','7000000051481342','7000000051722237','7000000052018581','7000000051721987','7000000051721990','7000000052725251','7000000051530150','7000000051530152','7000000051530157','7000000051546193','7000000051761150']})

desired_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'report' : ['7000000051722237','7000000051481339','7000000051721987','7000000051721990','7000000052018581','7000000051530150','7000000051530152','7000000051530157','7000000051546193','7000000051761150'],
    'match_err_scr' : ['10101.A','10101.A','10102.A','10102.A','10102.A','10147.A','10147.A','10147.A','10147.A','10147.A']})
```

What i have tried so far:

```
match = []
#Iterating scr rows
for i, row in scr.iterrows():
    #Checking for match row now is full row in scr 
        if row['scrq'] <= err[(err['p'] == row['p']) & (err['errd'] >= row['scrd'])]['errq'].sum():
            r = row.to_dict()
            match.append(r)
#Creating new data frame
report = pd.DataFrame(match)
report
```

Merge left filter later

```
report1 = scr.merge(err, how = 'left', on = 'p')
flt = (report1['errd'] >= report1['scrd']) & (report1['errq'] - report1['scrq'] >= 0)

report1 = report1.loc[flt]
report1 = report1.drop_duplicates(subset = ['n'])
report1
```

Nested loop way to slow and again not correct

```
match = []

for i, row in scr.iterrows():
    for e, erow in err.iterrows():
        if (row['p'] == erow['p']) & (erow['errd'] >= row['scrd']) & (erow['errq'] - row['scrq'] >= 0):
            err['errq'][e]-= row['scrq']
            row_to_dict = row.to_dict()
            match.append(row_to_dict)
            break
report2 = pd.DataFrame(match)
report2
```

Comment: Is this only a snippet of your full data? Because I'm not sure why this: err['errq'] - scr['scrq'] >= 0 : would be in there. It is true for all of them.

Comment: I also don't understand how you are applying your conditions to the rows. err[err['p'] == '10101.A'] and scr[scr['p'] == '10101.A'] each have three rows, but how would one check dates against each dataframe?

Comment: Hello Eric M thanks for your feedback err['errq'] - scr['scrq'] >= 0  we are sure that we have positive quantity if this is false quantity will be negative.

Comment: if row['scrq'] <= err[(err['p'] == row['p']) & (err['errd'] >= row['scrd'])]['errq'].sum():
 1) Using list comprehension in this example this is how I am comparing on condition this will be evaluated first err[(err['p'] == row['p']) & (err['errd'] >= row['scrd'])] 2) I am merging on left this is equivalent to err['p'] == scr['p'] and after this filter on conditions 3) Here nested loop check on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but required to help understand the question.
@B02T, this is what I am seeing as a slice of the data.

So I am correct in that you are only comparing scr.loc[0] to err.loc[3], scr.loc[1] to err.loc[1] and scr.loc[2] to err.loc[2] ? Or are you comparing each row in scr to each row in err?

Looking at the desired_result, I don't understand how scr.loc[2] could be in the desired_result since, using err.loc[2], (err['errd'] >= scr['srcd']) evals to False. And, following the same methodology, scr.loc[1] should be in desired_result.

```
>>> err[err['p'] == '10101.A']
         p       errd  errq   
3  10101.A  13-5-2022     1   
1  10101.A  16-5-2022     1   
2  10101.A   4-5-2022     1   
>>> scr[scr['p'] == '10101.A']
         p       scrd  scrq                 n
0  10101.A  10-5-2022     1  7000000051481339
1  10101.A  10-5-2022     1  7000000051481342
2  10101.A   9-5-2022     1  7000000051722237
>>> desired_result
             report match_err_scr
0  7000000051722237       10101.A
1  7000000051481339       10101.A
2  7000000051721987       10102.A
3  7000000051721990       10102.A
4  7000000052018581       10102.A
5  7000000051530150       10147.A
6  7000000051530152       10147.A
7  7000000051530157       10147.A
8  7000000051546193       10147.A
9  7000000051761150       10147.A
```

Comment: Hello @Eric M thanks for the feedback, the desired_result is from old vba code, I am not sure what it does think that is nested loop goes for each row but sorts err['errd'] ASC and scr['p'] ASC

Comment: Ok. I guess at this point I don't know how to help further, because the desired_result doesn't make sense to me. ...2237 in 'match_err_scr' doesn't seem like it should be there.

Comment: Imagine two nested loops, and sorted scr['scrd'] 2  10101.A   9-5-2022     1  7000000051722237 goes first inline and it checks conditions with  10101.A   4-5-2022     1 and conditions are not met but they are met on the second iteration with next row inline , that's why 7000000051722237